# Calling Unity method convention: yield and SendMessage

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

The two main ways for calling methods in Unity are:

- [SendMessage()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html)
- [Coroutines with yield](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Coroutines_26_Yield.html)

I have already asked about the different situations for using them and it seems like that:

- gameObject.SedMessage(): no inmediatly actions. Good for modularity.
- yield script.Function(): inmtediatly actions. The objects have to know more about the different callings, in other case, debugging could be a hard task.

However, I still haven't it clear at all. For example, if I have a game with its own rules, what should be the default situation?

Also I found other problem: if I call script.function() without yield, Unity only executes the part of the code in the first frame, so the rest of the function wouldn't work. It's understandly but problematic.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to call a function, which is much faster than `SendMessage()` and `Coroutines`

Get a reference to an object then simply call the function.

`reference.YourFunction();`

To get a reference you can find your object at the start of the game. Then use the [**GetComponent()**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) function to find the class attached to the GameObject.

```
private MyObject reference;

void Awake()
{
    reference GameObject.Find("MyObject").GetComponent<MyObject>();
}
```

---

If your game has its own rules, then don't worry too much about how you call your functions. Remember, **it is programming you can do what ever you want**.

Comment: Even though your solution "works", it has a similar problem as SendMessage... You're passing a string, so you have to track all references manually (strings aren't affected if you refactor your classes/methods/whatever). However, this solution adds one more problem - tight coupling. One last note - yes, it's the decision for the programmer how will he/she handle the problems, BUT people should at least try to write the best/cleanest/most efficient code. If not for other people who may get the project after them, at least for themselves, if they need to add more functionality later.

Comment: @walther OP is asking for a way to call a function in a case which is named the "default situation". I have simply given `reference.YourFunction();` as the go to way, instead of `SendMessage`. The part of the code which you call "track all references manually" is only a sample way of getting a reference. There are better ways to accomplish this, for example creating an object pool that instantiates the objects. However, that is out of the scope of this question. That is, it falls under maintaining the references not how to call them. Either way, please post your answer, I'd gladly upvote it.